# Good internet but horrible ping?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

My old router did not work anymore, so I switched to another exact same (AirPort Extreme) and ever since, I have gotten horrible ping (300-400+ ms), I still get 300-500 MB/s download and upload speed though.

When I use [Speedtest](http://speedtest.net), it tried to use servers in Denmark and Scania, and now more recently in Finland, which is pretty far away from where I live (compared to the amount of servers that are close to me), in Stockholm, I contacted my ISP about this and they insisted nothing was wrong. I am guessing this might have something to do with my bad ping? It might not have because I still get bad ping when I force it to use Stockholm servers.

Comment: Is the slow ping (you didn't say to where) actually a problem? Did you ping an IP address or the name of a server?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yeah, onlin games lag a lot. The ping was measured with speedtest or pingtest, pinging individual websites are not slow.

Comment: Sounds like you (ie your ISP) have a routing issue, but you haven't provided enough information to be sure. Please provide some tracert output for a well known site (for example www.bbc.co.uk) and for one of the game servers where you are having lag issues. If you are running Windows then pathping output would be even better. Please [edit] the question and include the results.

Comment: @DavidPostill running traceroute on google and bbc for example, I get good ping. I could not find the game servers, (it's through steam), I tried using tcpdump but I couldn't point to which one of the hundreds of lines were the game server.

Comment: I'm not a gamer so I can;t help you with steam :/